# How can a number, around pow(2,39), be too large for a 64-bit integer value?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, integer-overflow

I'm working with Progress-4GL, release 11.6, appBuilder and procedure editor.

I have a string with value "1000000000000", which I like to convert to an integer number.
First I tried to do this using a simple conversion, but this didn't work:

```
Result = INT(value). => runtime error 15747.
```

As the mentioned value is about `2^39` and `INT` seems to be used for 32-bit values, this seems to be correct.

So, I decided to use a larger datatype, `INT64`, but this seems to give the same error message:

```
Result = INT64(value). => again runtime 15747.
```

How is this possible? How can a 64-bit integer not be able to hold a value around `2^39`?

Oh, if you want to know if I'm creating a 32-bit or 64-bit application, I have no idea, how can I know that from procedure editor/appBuilder?

Comment: Can you show **how exactly** you did the "simple conversion"? Preferably with that exact string `"1000000000000"`. A 64 bits integer can hold 2^39, of course.

Comment: @MSalters: Honestly, the exact value of the string is `"0001000000000000"`, but even the extra zeroes at the beginning, the number should not be too large for this conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ABL INT64 is not dependent on the process architecture of the Progress runtime (32 or 64 bit). The AVM hides such details. ABL INT64 can hold from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807

This here works nicely. I even added a few zero's.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INT64 NO-UNDO.

ETIME (YES)   .

i = INT64 ("1000000000000") .

MESSAGE "time" ETIME SKIP 
        "i" i 
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION BUTTONS OK.
    
    
ETIME (YES)   .

i = INT64 ("100000000000000000") .

MESSAGE "time" ETIME SKIP 
        "i" i 
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION BUTTONS OK.
```

Is your variable Result defined as INTEGER or INT64 ?